# Merge Facebook user profile picture with another picture

Tags: facebook

I am creating a app which merge user's profile picture with my custom picture. it is easy to do it with imagecopymerge but when i am doing it fot facebook user's profile pic. it isn't working I Am using this code:

```
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
$userpic = imagecreatefromjpg("http://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/picture?type=normal");
$mainphoto = imagecreatefromjpeg("img/back.jpg");
imagecopymerge($mainphoto, $userpic, 10, 10, -2, -2, 55, 55, 100);
imagejpeg($mainphoto, "new.jpg", 100);
imagedestroy($mainphoto);
```

It Shows An Error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpg() in /home/a7193625/public_html/fb/index.php on line 6

That means it's Not getting the user's image so what should i do? how to download the pic at my server or use it without downloading.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need URL to image, while using

```
$userpic = imagecreatefromjpg("http://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/picture?type=normal");
```

Just redirect to image url and outputs the image. This is causing problem.

You simply need a URL to user image.

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser(); 
$result = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/{$user_id}?fields=picture.type(normal)");
$result = json_decode($result);
$userpic = imagecreatefromjpeg($result->picture);
```

Using this way you will get the image URL and you can use your functions to manipulate image.

Comment: Showing An Error:

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/a7193625/public_html/fb/index.php on line 8

Comment: make sure you are getting Facebook user's `userid`.

Comment: Yup I'm getting the user's ID by correct way but it is not catching the correct URL dont know why :(

Comment: Its working fine for me. This error is coming for Facebook profile picture or the picture you are using??

Comment: check `mimetype` of image. Can you provide the pic link?

Comment: Getting error:


Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in /home/a7193625/public_html/fb/index.php on line 3

Comment: check have you correctly included Facebook PHP SDK and Facebook object is initialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your function name, it should be imagecreatefromjpeg instead imagecreatefromjpg

Comment: Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: Cannot read image data in /home/a7193625/public_html/fb/index.php on line 6

Warning: imagecopymerge(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/a7193625/public_html/fb/index.php on line 8

Comment: according to this http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php looks like you need to enable fopen wrappers. did you enable it?